# How to use years in a where statement to filter out time differences?

Tags: sql

So I am trying to select a list of Employees from a table named Employees, but only those who have been working at the company for 15 or more years.

I am trying to work with the variable 'HireDate', and compare it with the current date, to see if the difference is greater than or equal to 15 years, however I dont know how to write "15 years" as a quantity, nor make this comparison. What I have written so far is this, but the last line is what I am unsure how to write. Anyone know how to go about this?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, DATE('now') , HireDate) >=  15
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Your syntax might already be correct.

Comment: The answer depends on which RDBMS you are using, each has their own format, but in general you might need to use something like: `DATE_ADD(DATE('now'), INTERVAL -15 YEAR)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using sql server:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE DATEDIFF(year,HireDate, Getdate()) >=  15
```

Try this if you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, HireDate, CURDATE()) >=  15
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL (which is how the question is tagged), you would do:

```
WHERE HireDate < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '15 YEAR'
```

Date functions are notoriously database-dependent.  So the exact syntax varies by database and this might not work in your particular database.